# error in mysql query, does not return MIN value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get this query to work.

The query was written by "OMG Ponies" as an answer to: [fix mysql query to return random row within subgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796228/fix-mysql-query-to-return-random-row-within-subgroup)

The query below calculates correctly the difference in dates, but then fails to select the ROW (within ID1-ID2 pairs) with the minimum value of that difference.

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp4;
    CREATE TABLE temp4 AS
    SELECT x.id1,
           x.id2,
           x.YEAR,
           x.MMDD,
           x.id3,
           x.id3_YEAR,
           x.id3_MMDD
     FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   ABS(DATEDIFF(CONCAT(CAST(t.id3_YEAR AS CHAR(4)),'-', LEFT(t.id3_MMDD,2),'-',RIGHT(t.id3_MMDD,2)),
                            CONCAT(CAST(t.YEAR AS CHAR(4)),'-', LEFT(t.MMDD,2),'-',RIGHT(t.MMDD,2))))  AS diff,
                   CASE 
                     WHEN @id1 = t.id1 AND @id2 = t.id2 THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
                     ELSE @rownum := 1
                   END AS rk,
                   @id1 := t.id1,
                   @id2 := t.id2
              FROM temp3 t
              JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0, @id1  := 0, @id2 := 0) r
          ORDER BY t.id1, t.id2, diff, RAND()) x
     WHERE x.rk = 1;
```

I'm using the query to randomly draw one row within each group defined by a ID1-ID2 pair. I want the ID3 with minimum difference in dates to YEAR-MMDD (i.e. the absolute difference between YEAR-MMDD and YEAR_ID3-MMDD_ID3 should be minimized). If there is more than one with the exact same date, the query should select one at random.

If this were the table...

```
ID1 ID2 YEAR  MMDD  ID3 YEAR_ID3  MMDD_ID3
---------------------------------------
1   2   1991  0821  55  1991      0822    
1   2   1991  0821  57  1991      0822    
1   2   1991  0821  88  1992      0101
1   3   1990  0131  89  2000      0202    
1   3   1990  0131  89  2001      0102
```

Then the query should return

```
1,2,1991,0821,55 (OR 1,2,1991,0821,57 - ACCORDING TO THE RANDOM DRAW)
1,3,1990,0131,89
```

I'm pasting here a SQL DUMP of a TEST TABLE...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `temp3`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `temp3` (
  `id1` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `id2` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `YEAR` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `MMDD` char(4) NOT NULL,
  `id3` char(7) NOT NULL,
  `id3_YEAR` year(4) NOT NULL,
  `id3_MMDD` char(4) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `temp3` VALUES('1', '2', 1992, '0107', '55', 1991, '0528');
INSERT INTO `temp3` VALUES('1', '2', 1992, '0107', '57', 1991, '0701');
INSERT INTO `temp3` VALUES('1', '3', 1992, '0107', '88', 2000, '0101');
INSERT INTO `temp3` VALUES('1', '3', 1992, '0107', '44', 2000, '0101');
```

Comment: @omg-ponies @OMG Ponies I think the solution lies in ranking correctly also rows that have the same diff but are not read as first rows (i.e. they should get RANK =1 too!). I've tried         CASE 
 WHEN @id1 = t.id1 AND @id2 = t.id2 AND @diff != diff THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
 ELSE @rownum := 1

Answer (score 1):

This is a working solution. Thanks @OMG Ponies for your help.

```
SELECT
    x.id1,
    x.id2,
    x.YEAR,
    x.MMDD,
    x.id3,
    x.id3_YEAR,
    x.id3_MMDD
FROM
(   SELECT
        t.*,
        @rownum := CASE 
            WHEN @id1 = t.id1 AND @id2 = t.id2 THEN @rownum + 1
            ELSE 1
            END AS rk,
        @id1 := t.id1,
        @id2 := t.id2
    FROM
    (   SELECT
            t.*,
             ABS(DATEDIFF(CONCAT(CAST(t.id3_YEAR AS CHAR(4)),'-', LEFT(t.id3_MMDD,2),'-',RIGHT(t.id3_MMDD,2)),
             CONCAT(CAST(t.YEAR AS CHAR(4)),'-', LEFT(t.MMDD,2),'-',RIGHT(t.MMDD,2)))) AS diff
        FROM temp3 t
        ORDER BY t.id1, t.id2, diff, RAND()
    ) t,
    (   SELECT @rownum := 0, @id1 := null, @id2 := null ) r
) x
WHERE x.rk = 1;
```

Comment: +1: Well done, I was burnt out between this and the other question.